# How do I select the node values from the following XML using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, cross-apply

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
  SET @XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<member xmlns="http:...xsd" xmlns:xsi="http:...XMLSchema-instance">
  <Person>
    <Name>Jorge</Name>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Jorge</Name>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
  </Person>
</member>
```

I have a table with the following columns:

- Member
- Person
- Name
- LastName

How do I go about adding the values from the XML to my table?

If I'm not mistaken I'd have to do a CROSS APPLY but im not sure how to do this.

Comment: You could use `nodes() method` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<member xmlns="http://testxsd" xmlns:xsi="http:...XMLSchema-instance">
  <Person>
    <Name>Jorge</Name>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Jorge</Name>
    <LastName>Bond</LastName>
  </Person>
</member>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://testxsd')
SELECT
    PersonName = XPerson.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    PersonLastName = XPerson.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @XML.nodes('/member/Person') AS XTbl(XPerson)
```

which will give you an output of:

[image]

And of course, if you want to insert that data into a table, you can use:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://testxsd')
INSERT INTO dbo.Person(Name, LastName)
   SELECT
       PersonName = XPerson.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       PersonLastName = XPerson.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
   FROM @XML.nodes('/member/Person') AS XTbl(XPerson)
```